# ES6 equivalent of this Angular 2 typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular

I have this typescript and I want to write the ES6 equivalent. I'm learning angular 2 and would prefer to use ES6 over typescript, and all the samples are in either ES5 or typescript. If I see how this code is written in ES6 then I should be able to take it from there with any new code I need to write based off of typescript. Cheers.

```
'use strict';
import {Component, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

// Annotation section
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>'
})
// Component controller
class MyApp {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Max';
  }
}
```

Comment: For everyone who would come here to know how to convert Angular2 typescript to JavaScript, here's a handy guide from Angular2 cookbook: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html. Note that the examples are TS to ES5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 equivalent of your code is in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9GBn7fTBmwltpi4SHNzQ?p=preview). I've changed your code a little bit by adding a service to demonstrate a **parameters** property (see below).

**Explanation**

I think you don't know how to convert decorators and types into ES6.

1. To replace class decorators (such as `Component` and `Directive`) add **annotation** property to a component  . You can use static [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for this:

   ```
   class App {

     static get annotations() {
       return [
         new Component({
           selector: 'my-app',
           template: '<h1>Hello, {{ name }}</h1>',
           providers: [Service]
         })
       ];  
     }

     // ...
   }

   // or just add `annotation` after class declaration
   App.annotations = [
     new Component({
       selector: 'my-app',
       // ...
     })
   ];
   ```
2. To replace parameter decorators (such as `@Inject`) and types (`constructor(type: Type)`) add **parameters** property to a component. Again you can use static [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for this:

   ```
   class App {
     // ...

     static get parameters() {
       return [[Service]];
     }

     constructor(service) {
       this.name = service.getName();
       setTimeout(() => this.name = 'Max', 1000);
     }
   }

   // or just add `parameters` after class declaration
   App.parameters = [[Service]];
   ```

Comment: Note for people like me: though dependencies like that `Service` above get wrapped in their own array, `OpaqueToken`s do not. Now I know...

Answer (score 0):

Decorators (e.g. `@Component`) are an [active EcmaScript 7 proposal](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators). You can see the “equivalent” ES6 code by compiling your code with the TypeScript compiler and looking at the output:

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
import { Component, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2';
// Annotation section
let MyApp = class {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Max';
    }
};
MyApp = __decorate([
    Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>'
    })
], MyApp);
```

A slightly cleaned up, but not 100% equivalent to TypeScript output, would be:

```
import { Component, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2';
// Annotation section
let MyApp = class {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Max';
    }
};
MyApp = Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>'
})(MyApp) || MyApp;
```

Of course since all of this is still just at the proposal phase, it is possible that the syntax or semantics of decorators will change in the future, so you can’t necessarily rely on them working this way forever.

(Please also note that a 'use strict' pragma inside an ES6 module makes no sense; all code inside ES6 modules already runs in strict mode per the specification.)